# Как запретить фокусировать EditText с помощью клавиатуры

Tags: android, android-edittext

имеется 4 EditText поля. В двух из них я буду вводить цифры, а в других двух будет выводится информация.
Проблема в следующем - Если для поля написать`android:inputType="none"`, то при прямом нажатии на поле клавиатура не появится. Однако если сначала нажать на разрешенное поле(появится клавиатура), а затем на клавиатуре нажать "ентер", то сделает фокус на поле, где стоит `android:inputType="none"` и откроет клавиатуру.

Как можно сделать, что бы он проскакивал это поле и делал фокус на то, где разрешено?

Comment: а зачем для не редактируемых полей использовать EditText? чем TextView не устраивает?

Comment: Зачем вы используете `EditText` как `TextView`?

Comment: использовал EditText, что бы было подчеркивание поля, иначе стремно выглядело

Comment: @batman так просто назначьте для TextView такой же стиль как и для EditText тогда

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Может стоит подумать над использованием TextView?

2) Для того чтобы не было возможности фокусироваться и вводить текст используйте

```
    <item name="android:focusable">false</item>
    <item name="android:enabled">false</item>
```

Comment: `android:enabled="false"` может сделать текст и/или фон серым, лучше уж тогда `android:editable="false"`

Comment: Насколько лучше не известно. Если нередактируемое поле будет выглядеть как остальные поля, то это будет сбивать с толку пользователя. Он захочет отредактировать поле, а оно при это редактироваться не хочет. Хотя тут уже воля разработчика. Но не редактируемые поля должны отличаться от редактируемых визуально, мое мнение.

Comment: При переходе на это Активити - в не редактируемых полях уже будут значения, поэтому у пользователя желания редактировать не возникнет.

Comment: @batman боюсь жалания пользователей могут быть очень неожиданными)

Comment: Боюсь что то, что вы считаете "фичей" воспримется пользователями как "баг". Если поля не редактируемые, их нужно как то выделить из общего набора полей.