# Настройка параметра EditText, запретить вызов клавиатуры?

Tags: android

Есть поле с датой ,при клике выскакивает календарь, а потом еще и стандартная клавиатура. Как прописать, что бы на это поле EditText клавиатура не вызывалась?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как запретить фокусировать EditText с помощью клавиатуры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538901/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-edittext-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Должно помочь

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:editable="false"
```

Можно программно еще скрыть клавиатуру

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

А вообще это не правильный подход, Вам нужно сделать кнопку или просто Layout оформить нормально как кнопку и добавить иконку календаря для понимания, не нужно вводить в заблуждение пользователей, когда пользователь видит поле ввода и тыкает в него то ожидает не то что происходит у вас. Поле ввода и предназначено для того чтобы вводить с клавиатуры, зачем его использовать если вам это не надо?

Comment: все там нормально для понимания, если нажимаешь на поле с подсказкой "выберите дату", то понятно, что там выбирать надо а не вводить и выскакивает календарь.

Comment: @Магатрон3000 то что вам кажется что так и должно быть, то, это плохо, то что там написано это ничего не значит, этот тип поля для этого не подходит. Зачем вы его используете если потом убираете его основное предназначение? Для вашего случая есть элемент TextView как раз существует для того чтобы выводить в него информацию, задаете ему любые стили и все ОК

Comment: Я так понимаю, что Вы не разобрались в сути вопроса. В это поле пользователь будет вводить дату, при тапе на это поле появляется календарь в котором и происходит выбор даты. Мне клавиатура не нужна , так как всплывает календарь. Все просто - есть календарь - не надо клавиатуры.

Comment: @Магатрон3000 я разобрался именно в том что в вопросе, Вы сами себе противоречите, пишите что вводить не надо а сейчас пишите что пользователь вводит дату, он же ее не вводит, он выбирает из календаря, это не ввод, а поэтому я все правильно написал. Вам не нужно поле ввода, так как пользователь не вводит в это поле с клавиатуры, а выбирает из календаря

Comment: Давайте, каждый останется при своем мнении, Ваш способ помог! Спасибо!